# iOS SDK 3.10.1 Ambiguous Error

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

When i try to call callUser method i'm getting an error

```
VoiceManager.swift:72:28: Ambiguous reference to member 'callUser(withId:)'
```

here us the code

```
let headers:[String: String] = [VoipCallConstants.Parameters.Private:privateString]
let call = client.callUser?(withId: callingId, headers: headers)
```

it was working just fine before update to the new version!

Comment: What is `VoiceManager`?

Comment: it's the class that error occurred at

Comment: We need to see more code. What is the type of `client`? What is the definition of the `callUser` method?

Comment: func callClient() -> SINCallClient? {
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
        return appDelegate.sinch?.callClient()
    }


let client = self.callClient()

Comment: I figured out the problem that should remove the ? after callUser but that's new it was working fine before updating